# AntiDebug C++ Debug Error Visual Studio

Tags: c++, assembly

estou adicionando um projeto AntiDebug no meu game, o projeto em sí já está funcional, porém a parte do código que detecta o ollydbg por exemplo, está me dando um erro após eu compilar o projeto novo.

Resumindo, assim que eu compilo o novo game.exe e tento executar o game normalmente como um player normal, ele me retorna o seguinte erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Me da o seguinte erro na parte direita da imagem, e na parte esquerda tem o pedaço do código que eu acredito ser responsável pelo possível erro.

Minha dúvida é, como posso corrigir isso? o que devo modificar no código ASM para não ter mais este problema?

Eis aqui o CPP completo do AntiDebug

```html
int security::internal::cpu::mov_ss() {
BOOL found = FALSE;

_asm
{
 push ss;
 pop ss;
 pushfd;
 test byte ptr[esp + 1], 1;
 jn fnd;
 jmp end;
fnd:
 mov found, 1;
end:
 nop;
}

return (found) ? security::internal::debug_results::mov_ss : security::internal::debug_results::none;
}
```

Comment: Você sabe que isto é uma falácia, não tem como proteger de fato, está no máximo criando uma dificuldade para tolos, então está mais criando uma dificuldade para você do que para quem quer manipular algo no seu jogo.

Comment: Eu entendo, mas de qualquer forma, como posso corrigir este erro naquela função?